# How to Customize seekbar with stepvalues

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, seekbar

I need seekbar like this :

[image: seekbar]

I don't know how to set step values for seekbar if anybody has customized seekbar like kindly help me

Comment: i need to set stepvalues below seekbar, like in my shared image

Comment: i think he want the same Design , that's right ??

Comment: @mohammedmomn no sir, i need to set that step values(10,20,30)

like this [click here] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2viidnb6pbni99/Untitled1.png)

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254855/seekbar-with-visible-stepvalues-labels-for-each-position/21255094#21255094

Answer (score 3):

> I will suggest three ways. First to use comboSeekBar which does what you need.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33846964/3496570) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28084069/3496570) . [Library link](https://github.com/flagbug/android-comboseekbar)

And `secondly` you can simply change step in Seekbar using `incrementProgressBy` as [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7329277/3496570) doing. Or you can **setMax to 7** . And for each step `multiply the progress` with 10 as [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179938/3496570) does.

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
seekBar.setProgress(0);
seekBar.incrementProgressBy(10);
seekBar.setMax(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
seekBar.setProgress(0);  // change this to starting point... 
seekBar.incrementProgressBy(10);
seekBar.setMax(200); // change this to whereever you what to stop..
```

**To display a textview below the seekbar**,

Since you know the incrementby and max value, you can run a for loop.. and get seek.getProgress() first time, convert it to string and then keep appending incrementby to String....

Comment: i need to set stepvalues  below  seekbar, like in my shared image
(10 20 30 40 )

Comment: yes, incrementProgressBy(10); will do that.. so change the setmax(200) to your end point..

Comment: sorry @Sunny it doesnt show stepvalues in my output it shows like this
[click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrkkzc4qky940j0/Untitled.png)

but i need [clickhere](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2viidnb6pbni99/Untitled1.png)