# Android SeekBar with separators

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am making a custom SeekBar as following image.

[image: Custom SeekBar with separator]

after searching through internet, I couldn't find the best solution to meet for this issue. The following code is normal SeekBar control and please help me to change like above image.

```
<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekBar"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/sbumit_form_field_height"
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sbumit_form_field_top_mergin"
 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sbumit_form_field_side_mergin"
 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sbumit_form_field_side_mergin"
 android:max="6"/>
```

Comment: create a custom `Drawable` class that draw your design and set it via `setProgressDrawable` method

Comment: Thank you @pskink. Let me try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your image shows exactly <s>[this library](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar)</s> ([my fork](https://github.com/sswierczek/android-comboseekbar)). If You are not allowed to use it You can at least check solution and write Your own code.

<s>Check [ComboSeekbar](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/infteh/comboseekbar/ComboSeekBar.java) onDraw method.</s>
Check forked ComboSeekbar [onDraw method](https://github.com/sswierczek/android-comboseekbar/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/infteh/comboseekbar/ComboSeekBar.java#L114).

Usage example:

1. Open your project **build.gradle (root  folder)** and add:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/arnoult-antoine/maven/" }
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. In app main module (probably "app" directory) **build.gradle** file for compile library add:

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'com.aat:android-comboseekbar:1.0.2@aar'
   }
   ```
3. Go to your **XML layout** file and put:

   ```
   <com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar 
       xmlns:cbs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/comboseekbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       cbs:myColor="@android:color/black"
       cbs:textSize="16sp" />
   ```
4. In **Activity onCreate** init it with for example this code:

   ```
   ComboSeekBar comboSeekBar = (ComboSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.comboseekbar);
   List<String> points = new ArrayList<>();
   points.add("Point 1");
   points.add("Point 2");
   points.add("Point 3");
   points.add("Point 4");
   comboSeekBar.setAdapter(points);
   ```
5. Enjoy your Combo Seekbar:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But, it shows only normal SeekBar in sample project. Actually, I'm just new to android and please may I know how to use it.

Comment: @ThihaZaw see my edit I added detailed example how to use it.

Comment: @SebastianŚwierczek Unrelated, but how did you find the project AAR?

Comment: @jaytj95 it is used in sample https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar/blob/master/sample/build.gradle and the maven url is in main build.gradle here https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: I'm still a little confused. I forked this project and now I want to use my forked project via gradle. How do I go about doing this? https://github.com/jaytj95/android-comboseekbar/tree/patch-1

Comment: how to reduce size of deselected dot ? Please give some suggestion

Comment: @AnandSavjani it is not possible in this library but... I forked it as original repository was removed and added `dotRadius` and `thumRadius`. You have to download my new release [1.1.0](https://github.com/sswierczek/android-comboseekbar/releases) and use `cbs:dotRadius` and `cbs:thumbRadius` to change theirs size. Check out sample usage [here](https://github.com/sswierczek/android-comboseekbar/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml), and my changes to achieve this [here](https://github.com/sswierczek/android-comboseekbar/commit/895d2813fabccd327544b7b804b3996952e30589)

Comment: @sswierczek : how to set spacing between text and dot ? because its showing to much messy.please help for that

Comment: @AnandSavjani I added attribute `cbs:textBottomPadding` in version [1.2.0](https://github.com/sswierczek/android-comboseekbar/releases/tag/v1.2.0). Please also up vote my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are looking for is here

See [here](https://github.com/hongbeomi/DividerSeekBar).

It can customize the separator and text, and there are listeners as well.