# Not able to set step value in seekbar android

Tags: android

I am not able to add step value of 1000 to my seekbar.

**Below is my code:**

```
discreteSeekBar.setOnProgressChangeListener(new DiscreteSeekBar.OnProgressChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {

            int val= seekBar.getProgress();
            Log.i("Debug",""+value);

            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();

            budget = ""+value;
            txtSelected.setText("Rs "+ formatter.format(value));
        }
@Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

**How to get stepvalues in multiple of thousands?**

Comment: Why can't you multiply the `value` by 1000 before updating the TextView?

Comment: I have tried adding     value = value * 1000;     before   budget = ""+value;  but seekbar slides in multiples of 1 only

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? ekchang has answered your question, unless there is more than you are telling us.

Comment: See this detail Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40780369/3496570