# How to define a SeekBar's minimum value, maximum value and range? Is this done in the XML layout or do I need to define it in java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to define a Seek Bar's minimum value, maximum value and range? Is this done in the XML layout or do I need to define it in java?

I want to set min value(0.2), maximum value(3.4) and range (0.8) for Seek Bar using android studio. kindly solve this.

It will help me to integrate tflite file. for that, I need to set range first. kindly review my questions.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="219dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="366dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="280dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="343dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText tView;
private SeekBar sBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SeekBar sBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);               //id set for input;
    EditText tView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);            //id set for output;

    sBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        float pval = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            pval = progress;
            tView1.setText(pval + "/" + seekBar.getMax());


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //write custom code to on start progress
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            tView1.setText(pval + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you have already defined, it with `android:min` and `android:max`

Comment: I have defined it but I want to set min value(0.2), maximum value(3.4) and range (0.8) for Seek Bar using android studio.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7329277/9701793) can help you

Comment: I have tried this earlier. they have taken int variables like 0, 1, 2, 3, ...100. but i want float values like 0.2, 0.8, 1.6 and so on.

Comment: Then, you can search for a custom Seek Bar.

Comment: thank you so much. I have used this tView1.setText("" + String.format("%.2f" , currentProgress1));

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your SeekBar.
Please look this URL.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52350712/10247147

```
data class Range(val min: Int, val max: Int, private val defaultIncrement: Int) {
    val increment = if ((max - min) < defaultIncrement) 1 else defaultIncrement
}


internal fun Range.toSeekbarMaximum(): Int = (max - min) / increment


class RangeSeekBar: SeekBar, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    var range: Range = Range(0, 100, 1)
        set(value) {
            field = value
            max = value.toSeekbarMaximum()
        }

    var value: Int = 0
        get() = range.min + progress * range.increment
        set(value) {
            progress = (value - range.min) / range.increment
            field = value
        }

    var onSeekBarChangeListenerDelegate: OnSeekBarChangeListener? = this

    override fun setOnSeekBarChangeListener(l: OnSeekBarChangeListener?) {
        onSeekBarChangeListenerDelegate = l
        super.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        onSeekBarChangeListenerDelegate?.onProgressChanged(seekBar, value, fromUser)
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        onSeekBarChangeListenerDelegate?.onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar)
    }

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        onSeekBarChangeListenerDelegate?.onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar)
    }
}
```